# Fail to connect to mysql when I using spring boot

Tags: java, html, mysql, spring-boot, webserver

I want to make a web server with spring boot, but when I try to connect to my database, it comes some errors.
Here are some parts of my code.

```
@Controller
public class BackgroundController {

private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
@RequestMapping("/RankingList")
@ResponseBody
public String RankingList(Model model){
    String sql="select userName,score from user;";
    List<Map<String, Object>> list = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();
    try {
        list = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(sql);
    }catch (Exception e){
        return e.toString();
    }//return "RankingList";
}

}
```

Here are the dependencies in `pom.xml`;

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Here are some parts of application.properties, where the 'em' is the name of my database;

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/em
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=qwerty
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

Here is the `status` of my database.

```
Connection id:          3
Current database:       em
Current user:           root@localhost
SSL:                    Not in use
Using delimiter:        ;
Server version:         5.7.18-log MySQL Community Server (GPL)
Protocol version:       10
Connection:             localhost via TCP/IP
Server characterset:    utf8
Db     characterset:    utf8
Client characterset:    utf8
Conn.  characterset:    utf8
TCP port:               3306
```

But when I get the url:`http://localhost:4908/RankingList`, the output is `java.lang.NullPointerException`.

I want to get help, and I will appreciate it very much.

Comment: can you show where are you declaring `jdbcTemplate`?

Comment: Did you by any chance forgot to add mysql connector dependency?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add `@Autowired` to `private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;`

Comment: I have solved my problem and got the right answer. But why do we need do this (add @Autowired) for this error? Is there more information about how to use JDBC correctly in psring-boot? Thank you very much.

Comment: You can read official spring documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html It is very helpful

Comment: FYI: move logic to service and dao layers. Controllers have no purpose to implement business logic.

Comment: Please, mark the answer as right if it was helpful for you.